2015 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection
In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it here.

Here's how it'll work:

During the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, June 22nd at at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post one question per answer.
We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
At the end of the phase, the Community Team will select up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, containing 10 questions in total.
This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this new process, feel free to post as a comment here.

if anyone needs inspiration on questions: Ask yourself why you don't want to be moderator (if you haven't candidated) and ask this.

What do you think Crypto.SE's biggest challenge is? (E.g. question/answer quality/quantity, too many/few closures, too many/few questions of a certain type, bad tools/guidance, …) What do you think should be done about this (not necessarily as a moderator, it's ok if this requires the whole community or Stack Exchange staff)?

Votes of moderators are definitive. If a moderators votes to close a question he doesn't need to ask anyone and none has to agree before the question is closed.
With this in mind, will you change your voting activity (= vote more / less / equally often) if you'd be elected?

Great question, clearly connected with your other question regarding becoming a "definitive" reference in the site.

Unfortunately the feature request Add a way for moderators to cast a normal, non binding close/open vote has been declined.

Moderators have more to do, because they can do more.
Will you change your activity pattern (= be more / less / equally active) on Crypto SE if you would be elected?

You've just deleted / closed a question alone (with your super-vote).The author is accusing you of abuse of your moderator powers, via meta or chat.
How do you react?

Similar question already posted on the 2014 SO election here. I ran out of ideas and started looking around at those threads...

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8). 

How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments? 
How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?



In your opinion, what do moderators do? 
A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that? 
In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep? 


Everything you say or said will be seen as "definitive" / "official" reference in crypto. Do you think you're wise enough for this kind of responsibility?

That's tough. Although, strictly speaking, being moderator does not necessarily imply infallibility, it is definitively something to take into consideration. IMHO, it shouldn't matter, since the role of the moderator is more centered in non-technical problems, such as flags, closing questions, etc.

We already had questions on crypto where the author modified the question heavily (30+ edits), extended it and asked to answer the updated question, which was based on the answers given to a previous version.
How would you handle such a situation?
